# How to escape forward slash in request to make url-routers count it as part of uri parameter?

Tags: http, go, routes, gorilla

I have following route mapping using [gorilla/mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux):

```
router.Handle("/v1/data/{param}", handler)
```

when I call `curl http://localhost:8080/v1/data/hello%2Fworld` I get `404` response code. The problem is that in my microservice I would like to interpret everything that goes after `/v1/data/` as `param`.

Code that's capturing params is following:

```
uriP := mux.Vars(r)
param := uriP["param"]
```

Is it possible to achieve this using [gorilla/mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) or any other router?

Comment: Please post the handler code also where you are capturing the `{param}`

Comment: @Himanshu, post has been edited

Comment: Add the handler you are calling it seems like the url you are calling is not going to the defined one That's why the error is `page not found`. You can achieve that using `gorilla/mux`. Till now there is no error that can be generated using your provided code.

Comment: @Himanshu, yes it seems because `/v1/data/hello%2Fworld` interprets by router as  `/v1/data/hello/world`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add regexp, bc default regexp is matching until `/` or `?` symbols.

```
router.Handle("/v1/data/{param:.*}", handler)
```

Comment: What if he also has an endpoint at router.Handle("/v1/data/{param}/something")?

Answer (score -1):

For your question:

> Is it possible to achieve this using gorilla/mux or any other router?

Yes it is possible using [gorilla/mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#examples). There is nothing wrong in the code you have posted.

The error is `page not found` which means the url that you are passing is not registered with the mux router.

Pass `http://localhost:8080/v1/data/hello world` on browser. route will capture  any parameter after the defined url. Also print the captured url path inside handler request struct to see what is the requested url as:

```
fmt.Println(r.URL.Path)
uriP := mux.Vars(r)
param := uriP["param"]
```

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ yes I have checked it the space is `%20`.

Comment: answered my own question